# php - sql server : "set identity_insert on" not working

Tags: php, sql-server, insert, identity, sqlsrv

I'm currently working on php application, with sql server database.
I'm using the sqlsrv driver in php to make queries on my DB.

The problem is that I have to make an insert on a field which has Identity Specification.
I tried to use instruction "SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON", but it looks like it doesn't work with sqlsrv_query...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call command in a batch by itself and then perform the insert?

See [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) on SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF, it uses to GO to commit the batch before doing the insert.

Here is the reference manual for [PHP SQLSVR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php).

When I was writing VB script or C# in the past, I would use **query()** to return a result set.  The client side code uses a cursor to work with the data.strong text

However, this statement should be executed thru the **execute()** command.

Try the following.

1 - execute() - IDENTITY ON
2 - execute() - INSERT (S)
3 - execute() - IDENTITY OFF

See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I tried with and without the GO... My query works when I run it in SQL server Management studio, but not in php with sqlsrv_query

Comment: It still doesn't work... I get an error message which says that I don't have permission on this table, but my query works well without the "SET IDENTITY_INSERT...". Do I need specific permission to use this command? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you need permissions for everything.  Are you the accidental DBA or is someone else?  The database role (db_owner) will definitely allow you to do this action.

Comment: Okay, I just needed ALTER permission, which I thought I had... It works fine with the permission, thanks for your help, and sorry for the waste of time (I feel soooo noob...)

Comment: No problem, answering a wide range of questions definitely expands my knowledge and lets me see a variety of business practices.  I am glad you are all set!